# JOOQ PostgreSQL join resulting in InvalidResultException

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to join two tables in JOOQ and output the result as a `Map<String, Object>`, but I get `InvalidResultException("Field common_id is not unique in Record")`.

The code I'm executing is the following:

```
dslContext.select()
    .from(FOO)
    .join(BAR).using(FOO.COMMON_ID)
    .where(FOO.FOO_VALUE.eq(123))
    .limit(1)
    .fetchOne()
    .intoMap();
```

The generated SQL is something like this:

```
SELECT "public"."foo"."foo_id",
    "public"."foo"."common_id",
    "public"."foo"."foo_value",
    "public"."bar"."bar_id",
    "public"."bar"."common_id",
    "public"."bar"."bar_value",
    "public"."bar"."bar_value_two"
FROM "public"."foo"
    JOIN "public"."bar"
WHERE "public"."foo"."common_id" = ?
LIMIT ?;
```

I expected JOOQ to understand that the value I'm joining on will occur in both tables and omit one of them in the resulting `Record`, but it doesn't seem to do that.

Am I simply missing something blatantly obvious? What's the best/correct way to filter out the duplicate `common_id` from the resulting `Record` so that calling `intoMap()` returns a response instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2808

Unfortunately, the jOOQ object model produces duplicate columns from the `JOIN .. USING` syntax, as if you were using the `JOIN .. ON` syntax. The workaround is to list the columns explicitly in the `SELECT` clause, which is probably a good idea anyway in your case, as you might have accidental matches between any other column name as well (such as `last_update`, for example), or you can alias your table and its columns using [`Table.as(String, Function)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html#as-org.jooq.Name-java.util.function.Function-), generating a `[table_name]__[column_name]` scheme automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You've selected two columns called `common_id`. Try aliasing one of them. For example :

```
 "public"."bar"."common_id" as bar_common_id
```

Comment: Well, yes, that's true. But that seems unnecessary to me. I'm wondering, since both the fields are duplicates, should't JOOQ then be able to filter them out seeing how I'm doing a `JOIN`?

Comment: Maybe. But that's a different question!